# Sharing variables from IPyWidget embedded JS to python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I'm using [`jp_proxy_widget`](https://github.com/AaronWatters/jp_proxy_widget) - an extesion library for ipywidgets, and trying to use the `get_value_async` function to pass data from JavaScript back to python.

As far as I can understand from the tutorial notebook, this should work

```
setDemo = jp_proxy_widget.JSProxyWidget()
display(setDemo)

setDemo.js_init("""
    var testid = 10;
""")
    
class Testinfo:
    TESTID = None

def testid_callback(testid_val):
    Testinfo.TESTID = testid_val

setDemo.get_value_async(testid_callback, "testid")
```

but if I execute the cell this is in, I get an error:

```
Uninitialized Proxy Widget
new error message: ReferenceError: testid is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else finds this, the issue is the declaration of the variable:

```js
setDemo.js_init("""
    testid = 10;
""")
```

works fine